# Parse cookie by domain in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have two cookies with same name userId on client. They differ only by domain set. One is tradernet.com and another one is .tradernet.com

If I use $cookie_userId, nginx catches first one and it's not always th same one.
How do I catch cookie with exact domain in nginx?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but why don't you fix whatever is setting the wrong cookie in your applications?

Comment: about 15000 clients already have wrong cookie...

Comment: You can't, because browser doesn't send information about domain in cookie header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because the domain is not part of the cookie header content sent by clients. Here's the relevant excerpt of RFC 6265 about how Cookie header value is built :

> The user agent MUST use an algorithm equivalent to the following
>      algorithm to compute the "cookie-string" from a cookie store and a
>      request-uri:
>
> 1. Let cookie-list be the set of cookies from the cookie store that
>         meets all of the following requirements : [...]
> 2. The user agent SHOULD sort the cookie-list in the following
>         order : [...]
> 3. Update the last-access-time of each cookie in the cookie-list to
>         the current date and time.
> 4. Serialize the cookie-list into a cookie-string by processing each
>        cookie in the cookie-list in order:
>
>    1. **Output the cookie's name, the %x3D ("=") character, and the**
>           **cookie's value**.
>    2. If there is an unprocessed cookie in the cookie-list, output
>           the characters %x3B and %x20 ("; ").